# Merge sge into gridengine

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

The tags [sge](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sge) and [gridengine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gridengine) should be merged as they both refer to the family of cluster batch schedulers descended from Sun Grid Engine.  I suggest making `sge` an alias to `gridengine`.  While the Son of Grid Engine fork has picked up the initialization sge its predominantly used generically and the questions currently tagged `sge` are not specific to Son of Grid Engine (indeed one specifically refers to the competing Open Grid Scheduler fork). SGE also works as an expansion of Scalable Grid Engine which is the name Scalable Logic use for their supported version of the Open Grid Scheduler fork of Grid Engine.

Comment: There's now [Son of Grid Engine](https://arc.liv.ac.uk/trac/SGE) which reuses the same abbreviation (SGE). It is a continuation of Oracle Grid Engine (OGE, formerly Sun Grid Engine) but it differs from [Grid Scheduler](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/) and from the commercial offerings (such as [Univa's](http://www.univa.com/)).

Comment: While Son of Grid Engine does use the SGE abreviation my impression is most people use it more generically to refer to all of the various forks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the correct thing to do here is to retag things *out* of [sge](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sge), not merge the two.

- the questions currently tagged sge are not specific to Son of Grid Engine
- SGE also works as an expansion of Scalable Grid Engine which is the name Scalable Logic use for their supported version of the Open Grid Scheduler fork of Grid Engine
- While Son of Grid Engine does use the SGE abreviation my impression is most people use it more generically to refer to all of the various forks

The first two say "The tag is used incorrectly or ambiguous", the last one says "The tag is generic".

To me it sounds like you need:

- [gridengine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gridengine) - the generic tag
- [open-grid-scheduler](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/open-grid-scheduler) - for questions specific to OGE
- [scaleable-grid-engine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scaleable-grid-engine) - for questions specific to SGE (the Scalable Logic Product)
- [sun-grid-engine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sun-grid-engine) - for questions specific to SGE (the Oracle/Sun product)

(Whether you "need" the three product-specific tags is something only the gridengine community can answer - Depending on how different they are you may be able to get by with just [gridengine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gridengine))

Comment: There certainly isn't a need for Sun Grid Engine as it was officially renamed to Oracle Grid engine.  The copyrights were then sold on to Univa who produce another fork  called Univa Grid engine.  The long term supported path for Oracle Grid Engine is therefore an upgrade to Univa Grid engine.  I disagree that the first two tags say that 'The tag is used incorrectly or ambiguous'.  I'm pretty sure that most people who use the sge tag are using it as a generic term because that was the name it had before grid engine started forking.  They should merge because they're both de facto generic.

Comment: If the two tags get merged so that sge and gridengine are synonymous, I don't have a problem with it. My original comment was more of a heads up - people often refer to Grid Engine or SGE when talking about Son of Grid Engine, whereas I haven't come across anyone (yet!) using SGE when they mean Univa etc.